# Conditional Formatting Cells in a Column Only Containing Letters F-Z Excluding RR

Tags: regex, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting

How could I highlight cells using conditional formatting if I want to only highlight cells containing letters F-Z? The formula would also need to exclude RR.

For example, if a cell in that column contains RR or any letter from A to E, I don't want to highlight it. But, if it contains any letter from F all the way to Z, I want it automatically highlighted.

Tried using regexmatch, but it's not working.

Comment: Share a link to a sample spreadsheet. I have questions, and the easiest way for me (or another of the volunteer contributors here) to get the answers would be to *see* the goal rather than simply read a description of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, "[F-Z]")*(REGEXMATCH(A2, "RR")=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, @player0